# How to extract the best features through NSGA-II algo in weka

Tags: weka, genetic-algorithm

I want to perform the best features selection that should be helpful in best classification results in the form of precision and recall, through NSGA-II in weka.

How can I perform this? Can anyone give me blueprint for this task? Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [paper](http://www.iitk.ac.in/kangal/Deb_NSGA-II.pdf) can help you to choose the complements to use in weka.